# Deserialization json array with different objects - jackson/spring

Tags: java, spring, jackson, deserialization

i have a strange json array string:

```
[
  {
    "schema": "Cancel",
    "version": "1.0.0"
  },
  {
    "mandatory": true,
    "id": "uuid"
  }
]
```

It looks like its array of two different objects like :

```
class Object1 {
private String schema;
private String version;
}
```

and

```
class Object2{
private boolean mandatory;
private String id;
}
```

when i call Spring Rest template like:

```
restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(), ObjectFull[].class)
                .getBody();
```

Where ObjectFull is Object with fields from those two previous objects (Object1, Object2).

I'm getting array of two objects. First has some fields and second has other. 
Everything works as it should.

However i find building response using `objectFull[0].getSchema()` not good enough.

Is there any option that by using Jackson annotations combine those two object into one thorough process of deserialization ?

And instead of two elements array of `ObjectFull[]` get simple `ObjectFull`  with all fields?

Comment: It's so strange situation that, I think, you need to implement custom deserialiser. In case you do not want to do that you need to deserialise it to list/array of `Map` objects and using [updateValue](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#updateValue-T-java.lang.Object-) method you can merge list to an expected object. Please, let me know if you need help with this or some example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way of dealing with it is to create class :

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;

public class ObjectFull extends JsonDeserializer

and implement required methods

Answer (score 0):

Because that json is the representation of a List, you can't deserialize two objects from it into one with all the fields filled up. If you know for sure that you will always receive a list with two objects (that complement eachother) you can write a simple function that receive that json and read the List, and then create an object in which you set up the fields with the values from both list elements, and the return that object.